# How do I add a "skip backward/forward" button to my Kodi on-screen display?

Tags: video

When watching DVDs with [Kodi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kodi&hl=en) on my Android device, the on-screen display offers the following buttons (tried both pre-packaged skins):

- <kbd>|<</kbd>: Skip backward one chapter
- <kbd><<</kbd>: Rewind
- <kbd>></kbd>/<kbd>II</kbd>: Play/Pause
- <kbd>>></kbd>: Fast forward
- <kbd>>|</kbd>: Skip forward one chapter

I'd like the <kbd><<</kbd> and <kbd>>></kbd> buttons to "skip +/-10 seconds" instead of doing an analog-style rewind/fast-forward.

How can I modify that behavior? My Kodi version seems to support that feature *in general*, since I can [modify the skip steps](http://kodi.wiki/view/Skip_steps) in Settings/Videos/Playback.

(I'll be extra thankful if you suggest a solution where I don't have to fiddle around with a text editor on my phone, but I'm willing to accept that, if there is no other solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the current version of KODI on android, I was able to swipe left or right with one finger to jump +/-10 seconds. If you swipe multiple times in the same direction it'll jump 30 secs, a min etc based on your settings in the video section (System>Video>Playback>Skip steps...) 
Make sure to click Settings Level in the lower left hand corner to advanced or Expert to see these options.
Other touch screen settings can be found here:
http://kodi.wiki/view/Touch_controls

Or search "touch controls KODI" in google. 
That site speaks of the text editing options for keymaps etc if you want to go that route for further customization of your Kodi settings.
I hope this helps!

Comment: I just realized you were probably referring to a device that is not your Android phone since you mentioned DVDs. Since that is the case, are you able to connect a Bluetooth or USB keyboard and change the keymap file to something you can set to use the skip steps?

Comment: Great, works perfectly, thanks a lot! (And yes, I do watch DVDs on my Android phone.)